# A Single Sentence Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

One of my peculiar acquaintances introduced me to the world of puzzles, so I've started to dabble in making some of my own.

Here's a single sentence puzzle, where I want you to find a four letter word that is the answer to the puzzle, and a four letter word that is NOT the answer to the puzzle. You will be very sure when you have found either word.

```
I_ Y__ __AD TH_S RI___, _H_ A_SW_R ISN'T ___N THE A_SWER.
```

Oh, by the way... there's an L missing somewhere.

Hint for the Not Answer:

> **The numbers have two uses. One interpretation of the numbers will get you the answer. Another interpretation will give you the not answer!**

Comment: well prepared puzzle...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The missing letters, filled in, give

> I**F** Y**OU** **RE**AD TH**I**S RI**GHT**, **T**H**E** A**N**SW**E**R ISN'T **EVE**N THE A**N**SWER.

The letters added were

> **FOUREIGHTTENEEVEN**

The missing **L** noted in the puzzle comes in here -

> **FOUR EIGHT TEN ELEVEN**

**The answer**

> is **OATH** as found by [@Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46591/30633) -
>  it's the 4<sup>th</sup>, 8<sup>th</sup>, 10<sup>th</sup>, and 11<sup>th</sup> ***letters*** of the sentence.

**The NOT answer**

> is **THIS** as found by [@Sherlock9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46592/30633),
>  because the 4<sup>th</sup>, 8<sup>th</sup>, 10<sup>th</sup>, and 11<sup>th</sup> ***words*** of the sentence tell us ***THIS* ISN'T THE ANSWER**.

**If you upvote this answer, please make sure to upvote Deusovi and Sherlock9 as well!**

Comment: You've got the first half of the puzzle! Now to find the answer and not-answer :)

Comment: .... which is proving harder than expected :)

Comment: Stealing not required - I happily **give** you that clue - mainly because I can't see how it is right.

Comment: Well, the last sentence of your edit is right!
All information is utilized in the answer and not answer. I think it's quite obvious when you've reached either one, there's still a step or two to go!

Comment: Or 11? Since the not answer?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean. The numbers are all important but none of them are the answer or the not answer.

Comment: @Rubio deusovi got the answer

Answer (score 36):

The answer could be

> OATH

which comes from

> the fourth, eighth, tenth, and eleventh letters of IF Y**O**U RE**A**D **TH**IS RIGHT...

Comment: That is the answer, yes. But what isn't the answer?

Comment: An idea: reading it right vs. reading it left?

Answer (score 32):

Small contribution towards the not-answer.

> Looking at the fourth, eighth, tenth, and eleventh words of the sentence gives us **THIS ISN'T THE ANSWER**.

So I would guess that the not-answer is

> THIS

Comment: Nice! The puzzle is completely solved. :)